# Why am I getting NullReferenceException when anonymous method uses a variable declared elsewhere?

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-3.5

I assigned an anonymous method inline, and within that block of code attempted to assign a `String` variable that was being declared just before the method assignment.

That call resulted in an exception:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Here's the pertinent code:

```
else
{
    String imagesDirectory = null;  // <-- produces NullReferenceException

    if (Version <= 11.05)
    {
        String message = "Continue with update?";
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, "Continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Boolean isValid = false;
            while (!isValid)
            {
                using (frmRequestName frm = new frmRequestName(true))
                {
                    frm.Text = "Select Directory";
                    frm.atbNameOnButtonClick += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        using (FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                        {
                            dlg.Description = "Select the directory for image storage";
                            dlg.SelectedPath = "C:\\";
                            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                                imagesDirectory = dlg.SelectedPath;  // <-- I think this is the root cause
                                //frm.EnteredName = dlg.SelectedPath;  // <-- this does NOT cause an exception...why?
                        }
                    };
                    if (frm.ShowDialog(null, Icon.FromHandle(SharedResources.Properties.Resources.OpenFolder_16x.GetHicon())) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        isValid = ValidateImagesPath(imagesDirectory);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

At the beginning, the assignment of variable `imagesDirectory` actually causes the exception to be thrown.  But I believe it to be because of the use of that variable within the anonymous method.

Could someone please:

1. Verify or dispute my suspicion
2. Explain why I am correct/incorrect
3. Explain why the compiler makes this possible without throwing its own compile-time error

**P.S.** - I replaced the variable usage within the anonymous method with a different variable, and the error goes away.  So clearly, I'm right about the root cause, but I still have no idea why...

I am using .NET 3.5 in this instance.

**EDIT:**

Here's the method assignment further in...

```
public partial class frmRequestName : Form
{
    public EventHandler atbNameOnButtonClick;

    private void frmRequestName_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        atbName.OnButtonClick += atbNameOnButtonClick;  //this is a class that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly which line throws? it certainly isn't `String imagesDirectory = null;`, and `imagesDirectory = dlg.SelectedPath;` doesn't do anything likely to cause a problem

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm afraid you're wrong.  It is _precisely_ the line you cite that throws the exception.  And if you look to the commented line within the anonymous method, that change makes it stop.

Comment: have you tried pre-assigning `string imagesDirectory = string.Empty;`  I suspect it is related to how anonymous methods handle variables referenced outside themselves.  Since `null` is not a `string` that may be why? kinda reaching but that's what it seems like

Comment: @mckeejm Yes, and it doesn't matter what I assign, the exception is thrown.

Comment: then I would say it sounds symptomatic of anonymous method variable scoping in C#.  Have you verified in another context that anonymous methods retain access to externally declared variables?  Have you tried making it static?  This might help you down the path to truth (not necessarily great working code though).  `public static string imagesDirectory = string.Empty;` ?  **edit** you would also need to reference it inside the anonymous method as  `myclass.imagesDirectory` to test out that theory

Comment: @mckeejm I've had similar ideas, but I don't have a great deal of experience with anonymous method work, so I'm a little thin on knowledge to help me diagnose or even research.  I suspect, however, that it's something like that.

Comment: The only way that I can see where `String imagesDirectory = null;` could throw an exception is if there was a compiler bug in terms of the capture-context; what compiler version are you using? what makes you think it is **that line** that throws? Note: don't trust the line number in the exception (that can get out of sync), and note that the stack-trace can be misleading (especially for anonymous methods). Without that info, my first hunch would be that the diagnosis of which line is throwing is incorrect (easily done)

Comment: thinking about it outside the context of anonymous methods... if this were a normal function delegate... it wouldn't have access to it unless it was passed in as a parameter... so with that thought process it makes sense that this might cause an error.. but be allowed by C# (although I'm shocked it would compile just to throw that runtime error).  With that in mind... I think that my static suggestion may actually work (but is not really a great solution mind you)

Comment: @MarcGravell I think he meant the line inside the anonymous function was throwing the NRE

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't follow:  where what starts?  That code is the lot of it, as far as the method goes.  It's being assigned to an event that is declared within `frmRequestName`.  See edit.

Comment: Your using block around frmRequestName is strange. You are subscribing to Click delegate inside using block, as i see it that means the frmRequestName will be disposed before the click deleagete will invoke. If frmRequestName is a form, wher is your Show method? Or, what is the frmRequestName?

Comment: @jure I originally took that out just to simplify, as I don't think it matters, but I have added it back.

Comment: Can the problem be connected to the fact that the closure does not include the frm unless you uncomment your line? Try executing commented line and uncommented afterwards. Does it throw exception this way as well?

Comment: @mckeejm You should consider posting an answer related to scope.  Specifically, the thought you offered in your next-to-last comment.  That is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be symptomatic of anonymous method variable scoping in C#. Have you verified in another context that anonymous methods retain access to externally declared variables? Have you tried making it static? This might help you down the path to truth (not necessarily great working code though). `public static string imagesDirectory = string.Empty;`

The compiler understands that the variable is in scope at compile time, but at runtime the execution of the method is anonymous in the context of the class instance. The instance variable is not available, so it's reference is null.